# Form Mysql Join

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is :

```
SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE `USERID` = 148 ORDER BY `TABLEDATE` DESC;

ID  USERID STATE_ID   TABLEDATE              
96  148    13         2013-01-08 06:11:34   
554 148     3         2013-01-03 04:46:08   
25  148     2         2013-01-02 04:46:07
```

I want seconds highest entry of users in the table "MYTABLE" (=> order by STATE_ID DESC limit 1,1) whose date last entry is on date "2013-01-08".

I try to form the query but failed.Please help ?

```
SELECT F1.USERID,
  MAX(F2.TABLEDATE),
  F2.STATE_ID
FROM MYTABLE F1 
 JOIN MYTABLE F2 ON F1.USERID = F2.USERID WHERE
   F1.STATE_ID = 13 AND
   F2.TABLEDATE < F1.TABLEDATE AND
   F1.TABLEDATE <= '2013-01-08 23:59:59' AND
   F1.TABLEDATE >=  '2013-01-08 00:00:00' 
 GROUP BY F1.USERID
```

Output

```
148 2013-01-03 04:46:08 2
```

Expected output

```
148 2013-01-03 04:46:08 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the row that had the second highest value of `State_ID` you can simply do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT *
   FROM yourTable
   LIMIT 2
) AS sub
ORDER BY State_ID 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: sub-query are bad , please suggest by join

Comment: @SheldonCooper - I don't know really how to do this using a join. But, why not subquery? They are not always bad. Also, what if the subquery is the only way to do what are you trying to do?

Comment: @SheldonCooper You can put the date condition inside the subquery.